# Scrolling Problem While Loading Data with AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am developing a website using PHP, MySQL, JavaScript (JQuery + Ajax), I used customer scroll function and scrollbars, the problem is that if I load data with ajax the scroll function generates hundreds of errors saying:"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'top' of undefined" from the scroll function which is:

```
    function Scroll() {
        var contentTop = [];
        var contentBottom = [];
        var winTop = $(window).scrollTop();
        var rangeTop = 200;
        var rangeBottom = 500;
        $('.navbar-collapse').find('.scroll a').each(function () {
                contentTop.push($($(this).attr('href')).offset().top);//The error rises from this line
                contentBottom.push($($(this).attr('href')).offset().top + 
$($(this).attr('href')).height());
        })
        $.each(contentTop, function (i) {
            if (winTop > contentTop[i] - rangeTop) {
                $('.navbar-collapse li.scroll')
                        .removeClass('active')
                        .eq(i).addClass('active');
            }
        })
    }
```

and also the website starts blinking when I scroll to the end, I tried checking if the "contentTop.push($($(this).attr('href')).offset()" is not null, errors get disappear but web page still blinks at the end of the page.
If you can help, please share your answer, Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Can you please share the HTML for this?

Answer (score 0):

`var winTop = $(window).scrollTop();`. This line forces window to go to top of the page. This might be the cause for blinking effect.